# Can implement a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm a bit confused about a HABTM association with rails 3.2.11.

I have an Image model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :image, :article_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

And an article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :images
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :image_ids
end
```

I created a migration:

```
class CreateImagesArticlesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :images_articles, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :image
        t.references :article
    end
    add_index :images_articles, [:image_id, :article_id]
    add_index :images_articles, [:article_id, :image_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :images_articles
  end
end
```

Then I did rake db:migrate

Now I display checkboxes to connect articles and images when I update an image:

```
%div
  - @articles.each do |article|
    = check_box_tag "article_ids[]", article.id
    = article.name
```

When I check the first checkbox and update it can't create the association, the error is:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ImagesController#update

Mysql2::Error: Table 'project_development.articles_images' doesn't exist: SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `articles_images` ON `articles`.`id` = `articles_images`.`article_id` WHERE `articles_images`.`image_id` = 78

Params is:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5qUu72d7asba09d7zbas7a9azsdas8a8dss",
 "image"=>{"name"=>"Test",
 "description"=>"Testdescription",
 "article_ids"=>[]},
 "article_ids"=>["1"],
 "commit"=>"Update image",
 "id"=>"78-test"}

I see the table in MySQL Workbench, but I cannot look into it since it sais:

Error: `project_development`.`images_articles`: table data is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table

Comment: witg HABTM rails don't create additional table. Use `has_many through` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed to migration of table to articles_images and corrected the view to:

```
- @articles.each do |article|
  = check_box_tag "image[article_ids][]", article.id, @image.articles.include?(article)
  = article.name
```

This now works fine with HABTM.

Answer (score 1):

The migration is wrong, the table name join the plural of the two model names, but they are ordered alphabetically, i.e., it is `articles_images` not `images_articles`.

Either way, it is better to have a join model and then a `has_many` with the `:through` option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with has_many and will accept the answer when it's successful.